# Formula for factorial?

Tags: factorial

I need an equation that defines factorial without using factorial, that also works for $0$.
I have seen factorial defined like this:
$$n! = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots n$$
But if we plug $0$ into that, we end up with $0$, which doesn't work.
So what would be the correct way to put it?

Comment: $0! = 1.\quad$ See [empty product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)

Comment: When $n=0$, you have an empty product.  The empty product is defined to be the identity element, i.e., 1.  Alternately, you could use the Gamma function at natural values.  You could also use your formula for $n!$ except $n!=(n+1)!/(n+1)$ (although somewhat circular).

Answer (score 3):

In your definition, if we plug $0$ into that we don't get $0$. Because your definition starts with $1$, so the case for $n = 0$ simply isn't defined. Usually it is defined $0! = 1$.

You can therefore define factorial like this:
$$n! = \begin{cases}1 & n = 0\\
1\cdot2\cdots n & n > 0
\end{cases}$$

Alternatively, if you don't like the above definition, you could use the Gamma function definition:
$$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t - 1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$$
and the put
$$n! = \Gamma(n + 1).$$

Note that the Gamma function is defined for real values, whereas the factorial only for natural numbers.

Comment: I indeed think a piece wise function is the best. Because 0!=1 is chosen by "choice". In fact, I still have a calculator with red leds that gives 0!=0 (With no error message) That is one of the reasons why I keep that old calculator. But then inflation took place and we made 0!=1. So +1 for rubik

Comment: @imranfat You are absolutely right. Actually I think I have to emphasize the fact that $0! = 1$ by definition. One could define $0! = 42$, but the previous definition is just more useful and has many applications.

Comment: 0!=42 is a big inflation though :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Let $A = \{a_1, \dots , a_n\}$ be a finite set of numbers. Then
   $$\prod_{a\in A} a = a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$$
   and by convention $\Pi_{a\in \emptyset} = 1$, therefore you can define factorial as $$f(n) = \prod_{1 \leq k \leq n} k\text{.}$$
   In this case, $f(0) = \prod_{k\in \emptyset}k = 1$.
2. Also, you can define factorial in the terms of [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):
   $$f(n) =\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n}e^{-t}dt\text{.}$$
3. The third option is a combinatorial definition. Define $n!$ as a number of bijections $$g:\{1, 2, \dots , n\}\to \{1, 2, \dots , n\}\text{.}$$
   Again, $0!$ is somehow special, since you have to notice that there is exactly one [empty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function) $g:\emptyset \to \emptyset$.
4. The last one, I can come up with is
   $$f(n) = \frac{1}{c_n}\text{,}$$
   where $c_n$ are uniquely determined coeffients of the Taylor's series of the exponential function: $$e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}c_n x^n\text{.}$$

Answer (score 3):

When thinking about combinations, we can derive a
formula for "the number of ways of choosing k things from a collection
of n things." The formula to count out such problems is  $n!/k!(n-k)!$.

For example, the number of handshakes that occur when everybody in a group of $5$ people shakes hands can be computed using $n = 5$ (five people) and $k = 2$ ($2$ people per handshake) in this formula. (So the answer is $5!/(2! 3!) = 10$).

Now suppose that there are $2$ people and "everybody shakes hands with everybody else."  Obviously there is only one handshake. But what happens if we put $n = 2$ ($2$ people) and $k = 2$ ($2$ people per handshake) in the formula? We get $2!/(2!0!)$.  This is $2/(2x)$, where $x$ is the value of $0!$. The fraction reduces to $1/x$, which must equal $1$ since there is only $1$ handshake. The only value of $0!$ that makes sense here is $0! = 1$.

And so we define $0! = 1$.

[more here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223110133/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57128.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to work with 0, use

$$
0!=1\\
(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!
$$

The other options have been covered in other answers.